# How do I improve the resolution of a raster layer

Tags: qgis, raster-conversion

I have a DEM raster layer created from contour lines in Qgis 3.0 using v.to.rast to get my contour raster and then r.surf.contour to get the DEM.

The trouble is, somewhere in the process, the cell size for the resulting raster layer is too big and the 3D map is 'terraced'.

How do I reduce the cell size (make the resolution higher)?

Comment: @Joseph Perfect, thank you. I had to fiddle about with the cell size, not sure what units it's in, but 30 seemed to work.

Comment: Most welcome, glad it helped :). Will post the comment as an answer for the convenience of others. The units would normally be in metres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the GRASS tool [r.resamp.interp](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/r.resamp.interp.html) which allows you to resample your raster to a finer resolution by specifying the cell size.