# Improve the quality for a raster PNG in Georefrencing QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, georeferencing

I imported a raster .png file (convert from .svg) in Georeferencer, the resolution is acceptable but after the geo referenced layer is placed on top of the map, it becomes a blur.
[image]

I tried [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273875/how-do-i-improve-the-resolution-of-a-raster-layer) GRASS tool r.resamp.interp, but it didn't work, it just turns grey but the resolution is still the same.

Is there a way to make the resolution same as the the original raster .png?

[image]

Comment: In the raster's layer properties, try changing the Resampling from Nearest Neighbour (both when zoomed in or out) from Nearest Neighbour to Bilinear or Cubic. It might look a little less terrible. Otherwise, use whatever you used to convert the svg to a png but use a higher resolution there.

Comment: @she_weeds I had tried the method `bilinear`, `bicubic` and `lanczos`, all output are in the same resolution. The `Fasa2-7.png` is the highest resolution png I can export.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A thin plate spline transform is going to stretch and pull the original image in all sorts of directions. This is an inherently "lossy" process and you aren't going to get something out that looks just like the original. There will be "jaggies" like in your image, or you need to apply some smoothing and lose resolution.

The original looks good because it was drawn from a vector SVG with that grid in mind, and whatever drew it used techniques like anti-aliasing to smooth the jaggies in the lines. Once drawn, the vector info is lost, so the georeferenced image can't be smoothed like that. If you could georeference *the vector* SVG then you could get nicely drawn features because you have precise coordinate info in vector data, and not discrete cells.